# Beginner: I integrated a blog into my Javascript/React website, but how do I add styling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, blogs

I integrated a blog into my webpage and the functionality is there. However, both the blog page and the link that points to the blog post list have no styling

```
<Link to={`/blog/posts/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>
```

The code above returns the list of blog entry titles. However I want to style both pages to actually look better. The blog API does not come with any styling. What do I need to do ?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    meta: {},
    data: []
  }
  async componentDidMount () {
    const { match } = this.props
    let page = match.params.page || 1

    const resp = await butter.post.list({ page: page, page_size: 10 })
    this.setState(resp.data)
  }
  render () {
    const { next_page, previous_page } = this.state.meta

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((post, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
            <Link to={`/blog/posts/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        <br />

        <div>
          {previous_page && (
            <Link to={`/${previous_page}`}>
              <a>Prev</a>
            </Link>
          )}

          {next_page && (
            <Link to={`/${next_page}`}>
              <a>Next</a>
            </Link>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use an external css file. You can use className="CLASS_NAME" in your components. For example:

```
<div className="mycontainer"> ... </div>
```

Note that you have to import the css file:

```
import './ccsFileName.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways

**1**-Styling using class

```
<div className="myClass"> ... </div>
```

**2**-Object styling

```
  <div style={myStyle}> ... </div>
```

Css

```
  const myStyle={
   color:'red',
   fontSize:20
   }
```

**3**-Inline styling

```
  <div style={{color:'red',fontSize:30}}> ... </div>
```

for your reference [Styling and CSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Comment: Thank you! So where would I add this in here?  --> <Link to={`/blog/posts/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>   just wrap it around ?

Comment: @cryptodactyl just try this <Link to={/blog/posts/${post.slug}} style={{color:'red',fontSize:20}}>{post.title}</Link>